# Programmatically disable password confirmation pop-up in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, passwords

I have a simple password change form as below. It's part of a larger page, but this snippet serves to illustrate. There's no user identifier in this form - no login name, ID or other reference. It's not required because that information is stored as part of the session data on the server and picked up there when this form is submitted by an AJAX call.

```
<div id="passwordChange" >
    <form id="passwordForm">
        <table class="formbox dropshadow">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="currentPassword">Current Password</label></td>
                <td><input id="currentPassword" name="oldPassword" type="password" required pattern=".{5,20}" title="Passwords should be between 5 and 20 characters long"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="newPassword">New Password</label></td>
                <td><input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" type="password" required pattern=".{5,20}" title="Passwords should be between 5 and 20 characters long"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label></td>
                <td><input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" required pattern=".{5,20}" title="Passwords should be between 5 and 20 characters long"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="setPassword">
                    <input type=submit name=submit value="Change Password">
                    <input type=button name=cancel value="Cancel">
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

If I enter a password that Firefox has already stored for the domain in the first password box, and Firefox has stored that password for more than one stored user I get this box pop-up when I click `Change Password`:

[image]

The thing is, I might not be changing the password for any of the listed users, but I can't proceed past this point without giving Firefox an answer. This makes it impossible to change the password for a user whose password is not stored by the Firefox password manager.

Now, there may be a configuration option to enable or disable this behaviour (I'd be pleased to hear about it) but that's only good for my computer.

I want to be able to disable this behaviour as part of the page so that my customers don't run up against it.

Is there some HTML tag or attribute I can use? Is there a Javascript hack, or just a structural change I can make to the form that stops this occurring?

FWIW I'm running Firefox 37.0.2

Comment: you can't any more. most browsers have adopted this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906

Comment: @Daniel That bug report refers to the 'autocomplete' attribute. This is not about autocomplete, but about Firefox asking for something to which there is no answer. If I have two users with the same password stored on a domain Firefox will only allow me to change those. I cannot change a password that is not stored. This might just be an edge case in my testing environment but it's a real pain!

Comment: true but the browser implementors are saying there's no way to control the password manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grappling with this for a while, I tried adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to my form. With this `<input>`, lo and behold, no interference from the password manager:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="currentPassword" name="oldPassword" type="password" required pattern=".{5,20}" title="Passwords should be between 5 and 20 characters long">
```

Now, this flies in the face of the bug report referred to by Daniel A. White (see above) and notes on web pages such as [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion), both of which suggest that the ability to turn off `autocomplete` is being removed from the browser. Perhaps it is, but it seems that it doesn't apply *here*, which is all I am concerned about.

(The separate argument about whether browser manufacturers should be unilaterally overriding the wishes of the site designers is a debate for another place and time).

**Footnote:** While fiddling with this I did something that should have been obvious, but wasn't intuitive: I clicked the red `X` and closed the window. Password manager disappeared without updating anything and everything was as I wished. I still feel that a 'None of the Above' button, or 'Not Now' or whatever would have been friendlier.

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML tag or attribute that can accomplish that.
This is Browser specific, not webpage manipulation.

Comment: I accept that this is browser specific, but I'm open to any fix, HTML or otherwise, that will work around it. I could implement a Javascript keystroke handler to emulate a password box, but that seems overkill when all that's needed is a 'none of the above' button, or for Firefox not to ask a silly question.

Comment: I do not believe this could be achieved via javascript. After all this is made so the user can choose which credentials to use (if more than one).